# C# application exits when I dispose

Tags: c#, forms

Basically I have a Login window which should close once the user logs in and show another window, for now I've just hid it(Form.Hide()) however I do not wish to take unnescesary system resources and I don't need the login window after I already logged in.

this is the code snippet where I perform the operation:

```
MainWindow w = new MainWindow();
        TimeRegisterApI.Instance.Windows.Add(w.Text,w);
        TimeRegisterApI.Instance.Windows[w.Text].Show();
        this.Dispose();
```

Windows is a dictionary that stores references of forms with their title as the key.
TimeRegisterApi is a singleton.
Basically what happens is that my application exits after I login instead of just disposing the login window, when I want it to dispose(close and go to the garbage collector.)

I know that having the title as key might cause duplicate key entries but in my current design it's no problem.

Comment: Change your design :) and show login window in MainWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I fixed the problem, basically what happens is that when the window that is run from `program.cs` at `application.run(window)` gets disposed it closes the program because it's the main window, I think it would be possible to do an `e.cancel` on the dispose event of this window, however I solved the problem by running the window in a new `application.run` like this:

from program.cs, relevant lines

```
 static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new LoginWindow());
        start();
    }

 public static void start()
    {
        if (TimeRegisterApI.isLoggedIn())
        {
            MainWindow w = new MainWindow();


            Application.Run(w);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make your window form login as a modal form which parent is your mainform
it will allow you to wait an answer (like a savedialog) and return to your main window form)
this is your main form so you exist